# How to get a count of occurrences in a timeframe of 7 and 30 days in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table `Emp` and I want to get the count of records starting from a particular date to next seven days for each unique ID.

For instance, there are two occurrences of ID1 each day from 2020-11-01 to 2020-11-07, then the count for this ID would be 14.

Next, the count would start from 2020-11-08 to 2020-11-14 and so on for each given ID. The same question holds for a range of 30 days.

I have tried `DATEADD()`, `GETDATE()` and `DATEDIFF()`, but none of them return the correct output.

It's easy to get the count for a given date but seems a bit tricky to get the same for a range. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the query with `datediff()` that "didn’t work" (I assure you it correctly gives you the output you ask for) and a small sample of data, together with the result you expect to see for that data.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEADD(), GETDATE() and DATEDIFF() are product specific functions.)

Comment: SELECT ID, DATE_ID , COUNT(*) AS CountPerDay
FROM Emp
WHERE  MONTH(DATE_ID)>= '11' AND YEAR(DATE_ID)>='2021'
GROUP BY ID, DATE_ID                                                                                                              This query is for obtaining the count on a given date, which seems easy.

Comment: And then, I am adding 'where DATEDIFF(DAY,DATE_ID,GETDATE())=7' in the same code to get the count for next 7 days.